# Help me identifiy this insect

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I found this insect in **Pune/India**. It looked like a fly, and it was running over a leaf.
Size is about 2mm-3mm. Is it juvenile of some fly species or is it not even a fly?

[image]

Comment: Yes, this looks a lot like a fly (six legs, two wings, shape of the body and head), but I am clueless what kind.

Comment: Another possibility is a Hymenopteron of the superfamily Chalcidoidea (parasitoid "wasps"); I base this on the clubbed antennae, small size, and what appears to be _very_ reduced wing venation.  If this guess is close to correct, good luck getting the animal much further (a good stereoscope is practically a requirement just to get to family, and going deeper than that may require a compound microscope -- as for species, what we see here may or may not have a formal name; there are _LOTS_ of Chalcidoids).